# Checking if string exists in array - what is the mistake here?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying remove duplicates from an array and build a reduced array. I receive an object required error. Here is what I am doing -

```
Dim LUT as object, baseArray() as string, sval as variant
'Dim sval as string ... ignore this
For I = 1 to n
    Set LUT = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ... other stuff
    u = 1
    for each sval in baseArray
        if not LUT.exists(sval) then 
            do something...
            LUT.Add u, sval
        end if
    u = u + 1
    next sval
    Set LUT = nothing
Next I
```

Please forgive if the code is unrefined. I need it to work more than being the most memory efficient, although unnecessary clutter is always to be avoided. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please ignore the "dim sval as string" line.

Comment: Which line do you actually get the error on?

Comment: OK - next most likely error `Next occurrence` should be either `Next` or `Next sval` (but still won't cause object required error - will just stop the code from running)

Comment: Thanks for quick responses. There are some errors in my reproduction here as I was trying to shorten the code snippet and remove irrelevant stuff. It is "next sval" - that isn't the problem. I seem to get the error on "if not LUT.exists(sval) then".

Comment: I think you will need to post the code that is giving the object required error.  That code works for me once I fix the things that stop it compiling (and assign default values to various unassigned variables).

Comment: (a) Not related to your error - Change `LUT.Add u, sval` back to `LUT.Add sval, 0` or `LUT.Add sval, u` - the first parameter in the `Add` is the key, so what you originally had was correct.  (b) Please post some code which generates the error you get because the posted code (with the necessary assignment of values to things like `n` and `baseArray`) works for me. The problem is therefore probably somewhere in `... other stuff` or `do something...`.

Answer (score 0):

This method exists takes as argument a dictionary key not a dictionary value.

```
LUT.exists(sval)
```

You probably may want to check another data structure like collections and this method **Collection.contains**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.contains(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The OP is using `sval` as the key when updating the dictionary (and using a value of `0`), so it is likely that `sval` is intended to be a key.

Comment: I think my understanding of the object was very poor. It is still poor, but I made an edit to reference the object by the value and set the key to a counter that I have within the "for each" loop, as you can see in the edited code above. I still get the same error at the same place - so it shouldn't be anything to do with that.

Comment: You are probablyu using Microsoft Scripting runtime. In this case check out this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h92h863(v=vs.84).aspx   The **ADD method** takes as argument **key and then item**. I think you called them backwards

Comment: The OP was originally using `LUT.Add sval, 0` and `LUT.Exists(sval)` so they originally had it right - i.e. using `sval` as a key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without the scripting dictionary, you can do it with string comparisons:

```
Sub DeDupeArray()
Dim MyArr As Variant, NewArr() As String, X As Long
MyArr = Array("Hello", "World", "This", "World", "Is Some", "World", "Data")
ReDim Preserve NewArr(0)
For X = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
    If InStr(1, "|" & Join(NewArr, "|") & "|", "|" & MyArr(X) & "|") = 0 Then 'Test if the element in MyArr exists in NewArr
        If NewArr(0) <> "" Then ReDim Preserve NewArr(UBound(NewArr) + 1) 'Add another element to the array only if it's not the first element to be entered (otherwise will be blank in address 0)
        NewArr(UBound(NewArr)) = MyArr(X) 'Add Element X from MyArr into the last address of NewArr
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Old Array: " & Join(MyArr, "|") & vbLf & vbLf & "New Array: " & Join(NewArr, "|")
End Sub
```